# Django filter, filter return more than this source

Tags: django, filter, orm

```
    print("Step 1",invs.count()) # -> 1000 # invs type: query
    invs2 = invs.filter(field___fields2__fields3=i) # i type:int
    print("Step 2",invs2.count()) # -> 40000
```

Is it normal for the filter function to return more than its origin ?

Thank you.

Comment: try `invs2.distinct().count()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theres an entire section in the docs that explain it

[Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Inside the big green note block further down below the "Spanning multi-valued relationships" heading it states

> However, unlike the behavior when using filter(), this will not limit blogs based on entries that satisfy both conditions. In order to do that, i.e. to select all blogs that do not contain entries published with “Lennon” that were published in 2008, you need to make two queries:

Answer (score 0):

The relevant information can be found in the description of [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).
A cite:

> Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.
>
> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. **However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated.** That’s when you’d use distinct().